# How to generate URL alias without %20 in URL?

Tags: 7, entities, path-aliases, uri

We have a custom field that is being used to generate the URL alias.

One issue we have found is that when we set the page to "Autogenerate URL Alias" and set the URL pattern to "`[node:field_custom_url]`", we are still getting "`%20`" where the space should be.

We have done the following, but nothing seems to work. We needed assistance to see what else needs to be configured. Ideally, any spaces should be replaced with a "`-`" instead of "`%20`". Any thoughts?

Current settings (found in `admin/config/search/path/settings`):

- Path pattern = "[node:field-custom-url]" (we even tried [node:field_custom_url], but it did not work)
- Create a new alias. Delete the old alias. = Enabled
- Separator = "-"
- Transliterate prior to creating alias = Enabled
- Reduce strings to letters and numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field token is failing the condition inside `pathauto_clean_token_values`, specifically as the token name has the reserved word `url]`.

See function [`pathauto_clean_token_values`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_clean_token_values/7):

```
function pathauto_clean_token_values(&$replacements, $data = array(), $options = array()) {
  foreach ($replacements as $token => $value) {
    // Only clean non-path tokens.
    if (!preg_match('/(path|alias|url|url-brief)\]$/', $token)) {
      // Convert language object into language code before pathauto_cleanstring().
      if (isset($options['language']->language)) {
        $options['langcode'] = $options['language']->language;
      }
      $replacements[$token] = pathauto_cleanstring($value, $options);
    }
  }
}
```

There's a `preg_match` which looks for:

- `path]`
- `alias]`
- `url]`
- `url-brief]`

in the token names, and your `[node:field_custom_url]` token will fail the 3rd pattern: `url]`. That's why your spaces are never replaced by the separator. You need to change your field machine name to be something not ending with the list above.

Comment: thank you for that information. When we created a new field with a different machine name it was working.

Answer (score 3):

It is proved that I wrote wrongly in the beginning, thanks @Beebee.

> I have read through the code of `pathauto` module. The module
>   implements the token replacement after replacing the space with
>   defined separator. So there is no clue by configuration. I would
>   consider it is a design fault of the module.

`pathauto` module clean the url only when the token name does not match with the pattern `/(path|alias|url|url-brief)\]$/`. You can find it in the `function pathauto_clean_token_values()`. Obviously, the module author would like to prevent the url alias to be clean twice. As your field name is `custom_url`, so it is escaped from the checking.

You can fix this by changing your field name or writing your own module as I stated before.

---

If you know how to create custom module. I would recommend you to implement [hook_pathauto_alias_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_alias_alter/7) for the purpose.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter().
 */
function mymodule_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  $separator = variable_get('pathauto_separator', '-');
  $alias = preg_replace('/\s+/', $separator, $alias);
}
```

Comment: I don't think we're reading the same code... pathauto replaces spaces with the separator during `token_replace` using a callback `pathauto_clean_token_values`, specifically by calling `pathauto_cleanstring` on the token value.

Comment: You are right, I missed some part of the code. I will edit this answer. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. Some details about it (from its project page, with some bold markup added to it):

> Provides one-way **string transliteration (romanization)** and cleans file names during upload by replacing unwanted characters.
>
> Generally spoken, it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.
>
> Whether you use **transliteration for URLs** (when using [Pathauto 2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto)), however, is a matter of personal taste. ...